# Json callback returns object how do i set my datasource to an item in the object in Kendo UI

Tags: angularjs, json, kendo-ui, autocomplete, kendo-ui-mvc

I am currently using KendoUI autocomplete to filter data when users type into a textbox.

I am having an issue on the autocomplete, when typing into the field the search start running and the service is called and the JSon result/Callback is being returned the issue i have is my result is being return in the following format

```
{"aaData":[{"SId":"934155","Name":"ABC CAMPAIGNS"},{"Sid":"926715","Name":"Inervation"},{"SId":"944847","Name":"International Technologies"}]}
```

This is my angular JS code

```
$scope.customersDataSource = {
    transport: {
        serverFiltering: true,
        read: {
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: "/customer/AutoComplete"
        }
    }
};
```

This is the HTML code in my view

```
<input type="text" kendo-autocomplete k-data-source="customersDataSource" k-data-text-field="'aaData.Name'" k-data-value-field="'aaData.SId'" ng-model="SearchData.Name" />`
```

when i type in the textbox the search icon shows up and starts searching but no results are being displayed, i have tried setting the data textfield to just name but no luck.

Please could someone assist in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to configure the Kendo UI DataSource is to specify the `aaData` field as the data items holder via [`schema.data`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.data).

Then, remove `aaData` from the dataTextField:

```
k-data-text-field="'Name'"
```

The AutoComplete widget has no `dataValueField` property, so remove that as well.